# reversing the order of an array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following array `[12,16,5,9,11,5,4]` it prints: `12,16,5,9,11,5,4`.

I want it to print: `4,5,11,9,5,16,12`

When I did `array.reverse` it printed:

```
4,5,11,9,5,61,21
```

It reversed individual numbers - any idea how I can stop that?

Comment: Huh? `>> [12,16,5,9,11,5,4].reverse => [4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 16, 12]`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```ruby
a = [12,16,5,9,11,5,4]
# => [12, 16, 5, 9, 11, 5, 4]
a.reverse
# => [4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 16, 12]
```

I'm not seeing what you're seeing.

**Edit**: Expanding on what Ben noticed, you may be reversing a string.

```ruby
"12,16,5,9,11,5,4".reverse
# => "4,5,11,9,5,61,21"
```

If you have to reverse a string in that manner, you should do something like the following:

```ruby
"12,16,5,9,11,5,4".split(",").reverse.join(",")
# => "4,5,11,9,5,16,12"
```

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like your array is actually a String

Comment: +1. The OP could use `array.inspect` to see whether it's an array or a string.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to reverse the list in place? If so then do:

```
>> arr = [12,16,5,9,11,5,4]
=> [12, 16, 5, 9, 11, 5, 4]
>> arr.reverse!
=> [4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 16, 12]
>> arr
=> [4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 16, 12]
```

Otherwise:

```
>> arr_rev=arr.reverse
=> [4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 16, 12]
>> arr_rev
=> [4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 16, 12]
```

Answer (score 5):

If your array is an actual string, try this:

```
"12,16,5,9,11,5,4".split(',').reverse
```

Hope that solves your problem!

Comment: Your code results in this: `irb(main):002:0> "12,16,5,9,11,5,4".split(',').join.reverse` `=> "4511956121"`.  That is to say, it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I just fixed it above.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = [12,16,5,9,11,5,4]

i = 0
arr2 = []

arr1.length.times do
  arr2 << arr1.reverse[i]
  i += 1
end

p arr2

>>[4, 5, 11, 9, 5, 16, 12]
```

Comment: A little more context around the answer would be nice than just blunt posting code. Keep in mind there is already a best answer selected with a single line of code. So ... explain your 8-liner.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.